# Venn Diagrams and Negative Numbers

Tags: probability

I am confused about creating a Venn diagram from the question below from one of the past papers as there is a negative number involved. Is this possible in Venn diagrams?

A survey of students in a lecture revealed that a total of $15$ played rugby, $30$ played football and $35$ played cricket. $4$ people played all three sports, while $2$ played only football and rugby, $14$ played only cricket and football, and $6$ played only cricket and rugby.

If $4$ people played all three sports and $2$ played only football and rugby, how is it possible to create the Venn diagram? Are negative numbers allowed, as $2-4= -2$?

Comment: There are no negative numbers involved in your problem. You should double-check your solution/reasoning.

Comment: Let me ask you this: What exactly are you trying to calculate with the operation $2-4 = -2$?

Comment: Well 4 people play all three sports so i put a 4 in the middle, then to calculate the rest of the intersections i have to minus from the middle which is 4.

Comment: Actually I think I understand it now, i got mixed up from a YouTube video, there he was taking-away numbers so that it all adds up in the end but my question is different to that, thanks a lot makes sense now was so obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw three circles such that each intersects the other two for your diagram. You will see that $3$ played only rugby, $11$ played only cricket and $10$ played only football. Try to fill in numbers into the regions one by one.

Comment: Actually yeah I think I understand it now, silly me, i got mixed up from a YouTube video, there he was taking-away numbers so that it all adds up in the end but my question is different to that, thanks a lot makes sense now was so obvious, yeah i get that answer now, thanks every so much